# Determining the dimensions of a MovieClip in millimeters from ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I determine the dimensions of a `MovieClip` in millimeters from ActionScript?

---

For example, I have a Flash CS6 document whose "ruler units" are millimeters and whose dimensions I have set to 200mm by 200mm.

[image: Document Settings showing width and height of 100]

Its library contains a Movie Clip with the AS linkage `HundredMmSquare`, which just consists of a solid 100mm by 100mm black square. The document includes a single instance named `hundredMmSquare`.

[image]
[image]

How can I obtain the value `100` as the width of `hundredMmSquare`, as I defined in Flash?

---

I attempted to solve this by assuming that the `applicationDPI` could be used to convert the original pixel `.width` value into inches, which could then be converted into millimeters.

```js
var pixelsPerInch = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI;
var mmPerInch = 25.4;

var width_in = hundredMmSquare.width / pixelsPerInch;
var width_mm = width_in * mmPerInch;

trace("width_mm = " + width_mm);
```

This did not produce this expected result.

```
widthInMm = 45.24375
```

Comment: I think 45.25 is probably correct. Note your square is still 100 _pixels_ x 100 _pixels_ (I see this from your screen shot). The ruler affects reference alignment in the design UI of flash, but doesn't alter the fact that Flash fundamentally uses pixels. Add an instance of the square to the stage in the UI and you'll probably see it fills 100 pixels -- and that the stage is 442 pixels square.

Comment: @JoshuaHonig Thanks for looking. I added a second screenshot to show where the document doesn't quite match what you're describing. The width and height of the instance are also listed as "100" on the stage, but you can see visually that it fills half the height and half the width of the 200mm document. This seems to indicate that the instance's "100" width is a measure of millimeters, not pixels.

Comment: Um your zoom value is 66%

Comment: Just remember that applicationDPI is not necessarily  device DPI

Comment: Doesn't it work if you use pixelsPerInch = 72?

Comment: @The_asMan If I zoom to 100% the frame will be enlarged as much as the square, and will still be twice as large.

Comment: @Strille Ah, it does! (Well, more or less. `width_mm = 100.54166666666667` because there's rounding.) So Flash's rulers just used a fixed 72 DPI that I should hard-code into my application. Want to post that as an answer? (I'll post it myself later, if you don't want to.)

Comment: @Strille I just realized that `Capabilities.screenDPI = 72`. I didn't even check this because the documentation led me to believe that it would be equal to the others. I don't know if this is just a coincidence or not... my screen isn't really 72 DPI, but this assumption might not be made at the same level as the Flash editor's.

Answer (score 0):

[Strille's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068376/determining-the-dimensions-of-a-movieclip-in-millimeters-from-actionscript#comment21191923_15068376) of using 72 PPI produces a close result:

```js
var pixelsPerInch = 72;
var mmPerInch = 25.4;

var width_in = hundredMmSquare.width / pixelsPerInch;
var width_mm = width_in * mmPerInch;

trace("width_mm = " + width_mm);
```

```
width_mm = 100.54166666666667
```

It's not actually possible for Flash to include exact millimetre or inch measurements in the SWF file because the format does not support those units. From the [SWF File Format Specification version 19](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf):

> The SWF file format stores all x-y coordinates as integers, usually in a unit of measurement called a twip. In the SWF format, a twip is 1/20th of a logical pixel.

The format also includes options that can cause some control points to be rounded to the nearest pixel, although I'm not sure whether this applies to my test document.

Because the format does not support millimetres some rounding must occur, as we saw in the value of `width_mm` above. Now, what values would we expect for different types of rounding?

```
# down to nearest pixel
Math.floor(100 / 24.4 * 72) / 72 * 24.4
= 99.97222222222221

# down to nearest twip
Math.floor(100 / 24.4 * 72 * 10) / 10 / 72 * 24.4
= 99.97222222222221

# up to nearest pixel
Math.ceil(100 / 24.4 * 72) / 72 * 24.4
= 100.31111111111109

# up to nearest twip
Math.ceil(100 / 24.4 * 72 * 10) / 10 / 72 * 24.4
= 100.00611111111111
```

None of these match the value of `width_mm` above. Perhaps because it's rounding multiple control points and not a single `width` value. At any rate, the original value is not available because of the rounding that occurs.

I am assuming that 72 is a hard-coded ratio in the Flash application. 72 also happens to be the value of my `Capabilities.screenDPI`, but this is irrelevant: the DPI of the runtime should not matter because I think the rounding occurs when the SWF is exported, not imported.

Comment: I've never worked on a screen that wasn't of res 72dpi however I suggest importing 'flash.system.Capabilities;' and defining 'var pixelsPerInch = Capabilities.screenDPI;'.

Comment: @Chadyk I'm not sure, but I'm inclined to think that the rounding-to-pixels occurs during Flash export, not at runtime, and so this behaviour should not changed based on the PPI at runtime. (It seems more likely that millimetres are only used in the editor than that they are included in the SWF but rounded when the SWF is imported. However, I could be wrong and haven't had any way to check the SWF to verify.)